# How to create a blank object, e.g. a list, using the namespace encoded in a string?

Tags: python, string, list, oop, object

I want to convert strings into blank list objects, which can then be updated/appended. How do I do this / can it even be done?

Imagine I have a string, 'blah'. I want to change this string, so that 'blah' becomes the object name of a blank list. In other words:

```
'blah'

def some_function('blah'):
   ...
   ...
   return(blah)
```

```
some_function(blah)

OUTPUT: blah = []
```

I know that if I pass

```
list('blah')
```

this returns

```
['b','l','a','h']
```

But instead I want the opposite, where

```
list('blah')
```

returns

```
blah = []
```

Comment: To get `blah = []` from `list('blah')` is impossible.

Comment: If someone says you can do it with `exec` or `compile` - DON'T - it's a terrible idea

Comment: Even if you could create a name `blah` within the namespace of `somefunction()` (which you can, albeit not in a nice way) it still would have no effect on the namespace from which `somefunction()` was called. 

What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Use a dictionary. `d = {}` then `d['blah'] = []`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen My thought as well!

Answer (score 0):

Moving on from the comments, a more logical way out could be to use a `dict`:

```
d = {}                         # empty dict

s = 'blah'                     # str
d[s] = []                      # empty list with the name of the str, blah = []

d[s].append("hello there!")    # appending to `blah`
print(d[s])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't in any meaningful way. I'd suggest heeding @Mark Tolonen's advice and using a dictionary like so:

```py
dictionary = {}
dictionary['blah'] = []
```

If you'd now like to add to `'blah'`, you can use `append()`:

```
dictionary['blah'].append(x)
```